# Spring Boot: How to create a composed annotation using @GetMapping?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm trying to create a composed annotation the uses `@GetMapping`, however I can't seem to make it work.

This works (using `@RequestMapping`):

```java
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@HxRequest
@RequestMapping(
        method = {RequestMethod.GET}
)
public @interface HxGetMapping {
    @AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping.class, attribute = "value")
    String value();
}
```

However, using `@GetMapping` directly does not work (presumably due to `@GetMapping` only being allowed on methods):

[image]

Is the no way to use `@GetMapping` as a composable annotation?

Comment: You've said it yourself. `@GetMapping` is annotated with `@Target(value=METHOD)` which means you cannot use it anywhere but on methods. The compiler forbids anything else. However, since `@GetMapping` is itself just a shorter way of writing `@RequestMapping(method=GET)`, your current solution seems just fine.

Comment: Thanks! Good to verify that I wasn't missing something obvious.

Answer (score 3):

As verified in the comments by @RobSpoor, **IT CAN'T BE DONE**.

But all is not lost, use `@RequestMapping` to achieve the desired end result:

```java
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@HxRequest
@RequestMapping(
        method = {RequestMethod.GET}
)
public @interface HxGetMapping {
    @AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping.class, attribute = "value")
    String value();
}
```